# SAS connect to sql server without odbc?

Tags: sql-server, sas

Is it possible to connect to a SQL Server via SAS without using ODBC?
The reason I do not want to use ODBC is that I heard it slows processing time.

If the answer is yes can you give a code example of how to do it?

Comment: OLEDB is another option. Don't know how they compare in speed. I would check to see what you have licensed from SAS. (SAS/ACCESS products)

Comment: Is performance something you really need to be concerned about? I've seen people bend over backwards to optimize for a 50K record file to save less than 2 seconds. How big is your data? SAS handles relatively large files with ease.

Answer (score 3):

> The reason I do not want to use ODBC is that I heard it slows processing time.

Don't believe everything you hear.

Yes it can be slow if used incorrectly.  But if used correctly you shouldn't have any speed issues.  Also keep in mind there are two ways to 'connect' to SQL server using ODBC.  The first is to create an ODBC libname, the second is to use ODBC passthrough.  They both have their own advantages/disadvantages.

Try them both and then make your own decision as to performance, and what works best for you.

Comment: Okay - What is the incorrect way to use ODBC? (Again I just read that if you type in none sql code via ODBC connect you slow proccessing time?)

And is there actually other options than ODBC and OLEDB connect to sql server?

Comment: An example of poor use might be complex SQL queries against an ODBC libname. Personally I haven't had the need to use ODBC libnames for many years, and last time I did I found they performed well on operations where you needed to read and perform actions over an entire (single) table.  For me, ODBC passthrough performed better in almost every other situation.  And surprisingly there are some other obscure options to connect to SQL Server, but nothing you would want to use from SAS.  A google search will find these for you.