# SAS SQL Server connectivity without using ODBC

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc, oledb

Is it possible to connect to a SQL Server via SAS without using ODBC?

If the answer is yes can you give a code example of how to do it?

Comment: it seems same question asked long back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337620/sas-connect-to-sql-server-without-odbc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS connect to sql server without odbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337620/sas-connect-to-sql-server-without-odbc)

Comment: That post does not answer the question. It only talks about ways to connect through ODBC, but not without ODBC.

Comment: Without what ODBC? ODBC license or the ODBC driver or the ODBC set up in the DSN? I think you'll need to be more specific to find a workaround.

Comment: SQL Server Reporting Services Rest API.  Do you want to not license any SAS/Connect products ?

Comment: I sense an XY problem here.

Why can't you use ODBC?

Answer (score 1):

OleDb. Those are your two choices. You could also use a web service to front the SQL Server db and use PROC HTTP or PROC SOAP (Preference would be REST/JSON). For direct access you need the SAS Access engine for SQL Server, ODBC, or OleDB.

Comment: Also, you can now use JDBC if you have SAS 9.4M6 and the new Access engine for JDBC

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can do it either as libname or in proc sql. i suggest using insertbuff-option when uploading. Just make sure your username, passwords and server are not quoted, like in oleDb connections.

```
libname My_libname odbc noprompt = 
    "DRIVER=SQL Server; server=&server.; Uid=&userName.;Pwd=&password.; DATABASE=&Database.;"
      INSERTBUFF=32767;
```

The second way is the

```
proc sql;
    connect to odbc as my_conn
    (noprompt = "DRIVER=SQL Server; server=&server; Uid=&user.; Pwd=&password.; DATABASE=&database.;");

    create table Query_result as 
    select * from connection to my_conn (
        select * from table_in_server_database 
    );
quit;
```

For more you can read in [SAS support page](http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/accessing-microsoft-sql-server-from-sas.pdf)

Comment: Both of those methods use ODBC - it's in your code.

Comment: @Reeza Ooops. With or without. Reading comprehension is !#!#!.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this technically uses ODBC/OLEDB, you don't need SAS licenced for it... write a VBScript (potentially receiving arguments passed from SAS) which connects to your data source using the system ODBC/OLEDB drivers, executes the query, and returns delimited records.

Then execute said VBScript via a pipe infile, read the records into SAS.

I do this regularly against multiple data sources (Informix, SQL Server, DB2, MSAccess/Excel).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on Chris J's answer but it is a cool idea. I would make some modifications (suggestions) to it. Skip VBScript since it is out of date and is not allowed in a lot of places. Use .NET Core/C# and Entity Framework. EF is a full ORM, easy to use, and will auto-magically discover the entire DB structure on almost every db out there. Stream the data back using a memory buffer.

Like Chris' answer but just updating it to more modern mechanisms. Will have to give it a try since it is a clever way around the issue.